# Creating and Dropping a random index on the table surprisingly improves performance in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, database-administration, rds

We face the following issue every now and then:

User reports the application is slow when they are trying to perform certain actions. After troubleshooting I find that any action being performed from the application side which is accessing a particular table (big table) in the SQL Server database is slow.

The database overall performance is good. If I create just a random index on that table and then immediately drop it, this seems to fix the issue. I don't understand why this issue keeps happening every now and then and then fixes if I create just any random index on that table and then immediately drop it.

I have an index maintenance job that rebuilds/reorganizes fragmented indexes every 2 weeks. I would like to understand that what does creating and dropping an index do in the background within the table which might be fixing this issue. Also, how can i find the root cause for this, I mean is there some kind of corruption that keeps happening on this table which is fixed when i create and drop an index?

I am using AWS RDS SQL Server

Comment: Sounds like it could be "parameter sniffing" https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options.  When you create then drop a random index it will force the query to recompile the execution plan, as the schema has had a change.  There's various ways to work around this problem (if this is indeed the issue), and the linked article gives some options.

Comment: Well, dropping an index would for a re-compile of any cached plans that would happen to use that index. AFAIK.I sounds more like doing the index operation, puts your big table into memory, making subsequent queries potentially faster. Are you monitoring PLE and Plan recompile on this system?

Comment: @RichardHansell are you sure creating new indexes will force a recompile? I would expect it to consider the new index on next recompile (not forced).

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought it was the action of dropping (not creating) an index that forced recompilation... the documentation on this is a bit vague, it simply says "schema change"

Comment: I am not versed with Performance tuning, still learning. I did the following test though: I created the index, checked the performance: no improvement. It's only when I dropped the index, the performance improved. The query might be picking up a different plan depending on the parameters passed but I can't control that as the users enter the parameters when they run the report. What can I do to resolve this?